# Issue in retrieving complete URL from address bar

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to retrieve entire url from the address bar, this is how it works, the url contains

> https://share.sebi.gov.in/proxy/580d11fe/https/sharelogin.sebi.gov.in/wps/myportal/Home/SEBI/SEBIHome/!ut/p/z1/lZBfb4IwFMU_DY_QW2kLLlkMbhOzuEiMBuzLUrBCI7SEdn7-uT8PMzFsu2_35pzzy7mIowJxLc6qFk4ZLdrLvufsdZXRJ7wkeAUvC4BkuSGLNNwCAEb5pwCuJoH5ZjIPAdL1BPH_-38m_c0_IuDj8Tni14j1Q_L4kUC3JGMYUvItGKv4G-QZ8bo15dc_E12GcY34II9ykEPwNlzOjXO9vfPAA9uIQbamVjqwslRBbc6B0h70p84elO1bUcmZMyep7yUjhEUx8QWh2MdYRn5cTQ8-AAXKphE-ltUtYmOsQ8VtEOq73a4AlXV5bN8BL43i8w!!/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/?authflag=success
>   "

I am getting only a part of the url i.e.

> https://share.sebi.gov.in/

instead of the entire url. I tried using window.location.href, window.location, document.referrer but still not able to capture the entire url. please help

Comment: How did you get the full URL that is included at Question?

Comment: That comes from the firewall page after authenticating the user.
I need to capture the entire url so that I can separate a part of it  and use it according to the need

Comment: Is the URL available without user authentication?

Comment: no, you will not get complete url but simply the website name.
after the authentication the firewall generates it by creating a session.

Comment: You already have a solution. What issue are you having implementing the approach that you used to get and include the URL at OP?

Comment: I am not able to capture the complete url when I use window.location.href.
that's my issue.
when I use window.location.href it captures only "https://share.sebi.gov.in/"
from the url "https://share.sebi.gov.in/proxy/580d11fe/https/sharelogin.sebi.gov.in/wps/myportal/Home/SEBI/SEBIHome/!ut/p/z1/lZBfb4IwFMU_DY_QW2k..."
I need to capture the complete url so I can separate the session ID generated (in this case it's /proxy/580d11fe/)

Comment: Not sure how that is possible?

Comment: the only issue I am facing is that I'm not able to capture the complete URL...
If I am able to capture that then my issue is resolved.

Comment: Not certain how to reproduce issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve